# Why does camera Y position change sporadically with PointerLockControls in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm currently working on a first person 3D game in javascript using Three.js. I'm using PointerLockControls to control camera movement, and for some reason, the camera seems to be jumping around randomly on the Y axis. It's not noticable in the game itself but if I print out `camera.position` in my render loop, it changes sporadically. I'm using WASD to call `controls.moveForward()` and `controls.moveRight()` which shouldn't affect Y position (I think, correct me if I'm wrong) but it changes nonetheless. This is the code of interest:

```
var controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera, document.body);
document.onclick = function () {
    controls.lock();
}

function loop() {
            if (wDown) {
                controls.moveForward(0.1);
            }
            if (sDown) {
                controls.moveForward(-0.1);
            }
            if (dDown) {
                controls.moveRight(0.1);
            }
            if (aDown) {
                controls.moveRight(-0.1);
            }
            // printing out camera position
            console.log(camera.position);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Edit: I should note, the Y position only changes when I move using WASD.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue with the official example (http://localhost:8080/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock) but it always reports a consistent `y` coordinate. I could imagine you see some floating point inaccuracies in your app. Would be interesting to know how to reproduce this...

Comment: @Mugen87 Should I post my app's full code instead of the snippet here? That way you can try it out yourself. I have tried the code on multiple computers and the same thing occurs.

Comment: Sharing the entire code would be indeed helpful for further investigation.